# Flexible order of columns in CSV with hard coded display of items in an app

Tags: python, mysql, database, csv, data-management

**In short**

I have a CSV for which the order and the name of the columns can change frequently. I am building an app that should load this csv into a sqlite3 db, retrieve a specific row and display it in the corresponding widgets: `Label_Name, TextInput_Address, Button_Date...`

The info each widget receive is hard coded and until now based on the index of the tuple returned by sqlite3 which reflect the order of the columnns in sqlite3 which reflects the order of the CSV.

How can I have on the one hand a flexible organisation of the column of my CSV and on the other hand a fixed, hard coded organization of my widget?

```
OLD CSV
"ID","Year", "Name", "Address", "Group", "Answers"

NEW CSV
"ID","Group", "Name", "Address", "Year_joined", "Answers"
```

Notice the order changed and "Group" became "Group" and "Year" became "Year_joined"

Some relevant part of my code:

```
#reading CSV and storing in db
with open(csvfile, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header= True
    for row in reader:
        if header:
            header= False
            query = "CREATE TABLE {0} ({1})"
            sql= query.format("MyCSV",','.join(["{} text1".format(column) for column in row]))
            c.execute(sql)
            insertsql = query.format(tablename,
                        ", ".join([ "?" for column in row ])))
        else:
            c.execute(insertsql, row)
conn.commit()

...

#getting the row I want to display
c.execute("SELECT * FROM {} WHERE id={}".format("MyCSV", 1))
row_for_db = c.fetchall()[0]

...

#dispatching the data from the row into each widget (based on column order)
Label_ID=tag[0]
Button_Date=tag[1]
Txt_Input_message=tag[2]
```

---

**In details**

I am building an app that should display all the data from an entry in a CSV file(up to 1000+ row, 28 columns). There is 28 widgets in the app, each should display the corresponding data from the entry:  Label_Name, TextInput_Address, Button_Date... In the app, the CSV is stored in a Sqlite3 into a db.

If the order/name of the column in the CSV (and thus the sqlite db) would be fixed, I would just have to do a sql to retrieve the row I want to display and then use the index of the tupple return by sqlite to dispatch each data into its corresponding widgets. 
But, the order and the name of the column of the CSV will change (sometimes quite frequently). So how can I have on the one hand a flexible organisation of the column of my CSV and on the other hand a fixed, hard coded organization of my widget.

I thought of using a second CSV that will keep track of the correspondance of current name and index of the columns and the columns' name and index that are hard coded in the app.

But this is curbersome, this second CSV would have to be edited it manually, which means at least some human errors.

Is there a better way of doing what I want to do?

Comment: Are all the columns names the same in all the different files? (but just in a different order). Could you add some examples of your source data and how you need the output to be for it.

Comment: @MartinEvans, Thanks for your help! I have updated my question. It would be better if the columns names could change but if it makes things too difficult, I could had this constraint.

Comment: The names can change, but you would need some kind of logic to map them back to a single preferred value, e.g. `full_name` -> `name`

Comment: Can you add some example headers?

Comment: @MartinEvans, please see my updated question. I asked the question because I wanted to avoid to manually maintain a "kind of logic to map" to prevent any sort of typos.

Comment: Really think about where data is deriving and why it changes frequently. This idiosyncractic, random process will be a headache otherwise. If an API, find alternatives; if web scrape, adjust such code, etc. Be proactive and not reactive to your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using sqlite's command line [`.import`](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#csv_import) facility called by Python's [`subProcess`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) which can create tables directly from csv files, so will read in *any* headers as long as it creates the table in the process and does not append to existing. Below runs the three commands in one shell:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

cmd1 = 'sqlite3 "/path/to/database.db"'
cmd2 = 'sqlite3 .mode csv'
cmd3 = 'sqlite3 .import "/path/to/file.csv" mytable'

p = Popen("{}; {}; {}".format(cmd1, cmd2, cmd3), shell=True, stdin=PIPE, 
          stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)

output, error = p.communicate()  

if p.returncode == 0:            
  print('OUTPUT:\n {0}'.format(output.decode("utf-8")))            
else:                
  print('ERROR:\n {0}'.format(error.decode("utf-8")))
```